# Guidelines for writing CSS to survive ASP.NET bundling

Tags: asp.net, css, minify

When I creare stylesheets for my ASP.NET MVC 4 web site everything works great when in debug/development mode.

As soon as I deploy the web site on IIS, in release config, some parts of the css are not being applied to the elements since they are not present at all in a single minified .css file that is being added to the page.

Making my declaration more specific - e.g. including id > class or stuff like that ususally solves the problem, but what are the general rules for writing css styles so that they are served to the client and are not filtered out by ASP.NET minification?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about ASP.NET bundling, it will bundle the CSS files in alphabetic order by default.  One simple way to make sure the files are always rendered in the correct order is to use a prefix on the filename, e.g.:

```
01.first-file.css
02.second-file.css
03.third-file.css
04.fourth-file.css
```

Having said that, making your declarations more specific and therefore less dependent on the ordering of files is probably a good idea.

Comment: My problem is not the order or availability of the stylesheet. Some styles from one css file are being bundeled, and some, from this very same file, are not. If no one answeres soon I will bring in an example of a style declaration that doesn' get its way into a bundled css.